# Table cell transform scale

Tags: html, html-table, cell, scale

In code below I try to scale a table cell. Cell scale but table size remains unchanged. How to scale table according to cell scale.

What is the space that remains between table border and cell border after cell scale?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function changeSize(){                     
             document.getElementById('dd').style.transform="scale(0.5,0.5)";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="border:1px solid black">
            <tr id="dd">
                <td id="dd1" style="border:1px solid red;background-color:yellow;font-size:40px;">
                CONTENT
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button onclick="changeSize()">Resize</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would love an answer to this